# How to simulate pressing Fn+F6?

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys

Method **SendKeys.Send** does not allow the press Fn key, which exists on laptop's keyboards. How can I simulate pressing this key from C#?

Comment: I am quite sure you can't. I believe the `fn` key is hardware supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, and you don't need to. The `Fn` key only exists as a key as far as the keyboard circuit is concerned.

When the key code is sent to the operating system, it looks just as if the function keys were regular keys as on a regular keyboard. The operating system doesn't even know that the `Fn` key exists, that is taken care of by the special keyboard circuit in the laptop.

To make a function key press on a laptop, just send the regular key code for a function key as on a regular keyboard.

If there are any other key combinations where the `Fn` key is used, they either have their own key codes, or they are simply not possible to send because they are handled by the laptop, not by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it, but I think you can do it with another way. Create a `keydown` event on a `textbox` and press `fn` key at runtime and then check what `code` or what `keyValue` it returns. Then use that `value` in your `SendKeys.Send` method.

Comment: And when KeyDown doesn't even fire?

Comment: I tried this and e.KeyCode == 255. If to try get scan code from C++ throught keyboard hook, then scan code is 113. I tried send this scan code through SendInput (WinAPI), but nothing happens...